# A webmin for debian systems that includes a file manager NOT implemented in java

Tags: linux, web-apps

A webmin that has a file manager to manage files on server.The file manager must be implemented using a non-java tech as my browser won't support java

Comment: Is the server using PHP or ASP (or something else)?

Comment: yes, i can install any normal stack on it

Answer (score 1):

I personally have used [Responsive Filemanager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) and found it to be pretty good.

Sure it does have some limitations: i.e. it is not an FTP client and AFAIK you can't modify file permissions with it.

Despite that for what it is it is quite powerful, and very UI friendly. It has a Java option but that is not required (nor default) and the non-Java uploader's only limitation is a size maximum of around 50mb.

It does require PHP on the server, and JavaScript active in the browser (and an HTML5 compatible browser but that's pretty much all of them now). A bit of setup is required but it is *not* onerous and there are very good [instructions](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/).

Responsive Filemanager has a whole lot of extra image specific features (like auto-thumbnai generation) but it is pretty good for everything else as well:
- drag and drop uploading
- drag and drop moving of files in the directory(ies) that it can access (which is *highly* configurable)
- copy and paste actions
- lots of (fast) filtering and sorting options